# Calculate difference between dates - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a requirement to calculate the number of days from 3 different dates. I need to run the logic to get an integer value from below pseudo logic.

**(future_date_1 - future_date_2) - Today()**

How to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You need to be more precise, what exactly you need? the day value of a date; the numeric count of a date since 1900 in milliseconds; the number of days between date_1, date_2, and today? be more specific please.

Comment: I need number of days between date_1, date_2, and today.

Comment: This question does not seem to makes sense. An integer cannot express days between *3* dates. You would need to clarify. And all the basic information like data types and Postgres version are missing. too.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve the date difference in days,

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2011-12-31 01:00:00'::timestamp - '2011-12-29 23:00:00'::timestamp);
```

OR

this also works pretty well

```
select '2015-01-12'::date - '2015-01-01'::date;
```

Now, you only need to use this logic and satisfy your requirement.